# GCP API Gateway: Cannot use path params

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, openapi, google-cloud-api-gateway

I'm struggling to pass the path params from my gateway to the actual endpoints.

Here is my Open API yaml:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: |
    Blah blah
  version: 0.0.1
  title: SSAuth
  contact:
    email: blah@gmail.com
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /v0/auth/users/echo:
    get:
      summary: check the health of api
      operationId: healthCheck
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://path-to-my-cloud-run-service/v0/auth/users/echo
      security:
        - api_key: []

  /v0/auth/users/type/{type}:
    post:
      summary: Add a new user to the user
      operationId: addUser
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: type
          in: path
          description: provider type of the user
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        400:
          description: Invalid input
        200:
          description: OK
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://path-to-my-cloud-run-service/v0/auth/users/type/`type`
      security:
        - api_key: []

securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    type: apiKey
    name: X-API-Key
    in: header
```

When I GET the first path, it works. But in the second path, there is a path param that I cannot find a way to pass to params to my Cloud Run URL. In the log, I see this `https://path-to-my-cloud-run-service/v0/auth/users/type/%60type%60?type=email` instead of `https://path-to-my-cloud-run-service/v0/auth/users/type/email`, and that cause my service to reject due to invalid type.

What do I need to change in my yaml to make this work?

Another issue I have is that the GET request gets 400 bad request if I put a json in the body even though I specify that it consumes application/json.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found the solution after digging [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions#path_translation).

It's the path_transaltion, here is the working yaml:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: |
    Blahblah
  version: 0.0.1
  title: Title
  contact:
    email: blah@gmail.com
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /v0/auth/users/echo:
    get:
      summary: check the health of api
      operationId: healthCheck
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://path-to-my-service
        path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
      security:
        - api_key: []

  /v0/auth/users/type/{type}:
    post:
      summary: Add a new user to the user
      operationId: addUser
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: type
          in: path
          description: provider type of the user
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        400:
          description: Invalid input
        200:
          description: OK
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://path-to-my-service
        path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
      security:
        - api_key: []

securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    type: apiKey
    name: X-API-Key
    in: header
```

Comment: have you tried with PUT and DELETE method?
I always getting `Cannot PUT /users/{user-id}` error

Comment: Yes, my delete works, and I declared it just like GET

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. It works for me as well. Thanks.