# Google API Gateway OpenApi Swaagger 2.0 to CloudRun Parameter configured for Path turns out in query instead of path

Tags: openapi, google-cloud-run, swagger-2.0, google-cloud-api-gateway, google-api-gateway

I'm testing an API Gateway setup on Google Cloud to access specific endpoints on a service deployed on Cloud Run.  I'm following the steps shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/get-started-cloud-run). We need to authenticate using an API Key, so the API Key specific configuration that went into the API Gateway config was picked from [this](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/secure-traffic-gcloud#securing_access_by_using_an_api_key) documentation.

The API Gateway config is as shown below:

```
# api_gateway_config.yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: myappapi
  description: API with Cloudrun Backend
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /:
    get:
      summary: Greet a User from service
      operationId: hello
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://myappapi-asldfjoiewjfv-uc.a.run.app/
      security:
      - api_key: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
  /reports/results/{id}:
    get:
      summary: Get Report Results for specified report id
      operationId: GetReportResults
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://myappapi-asldfjoiewjfv-uc.a.run.app/v1/reports/results/{id}
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: id
          required: true
          type: integer
      security:
      - api_key: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string

securityDefinitions:
  # This section configures basic authentication with an API Key.
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "key"
    in: "query"
```

For a sample call to the /reports/results endpoint as http://myappapi/reports/results/1,
the expectation is for calls to get converted to https://myappapi-asldfjoiewjfv-uc.a.run.app/v1/reports/results/1?key=MyAPIKeyHere.  But instead they turn out as https://myappapi-asldfjoiewjfv-uc.a.run.app/v1/reports/results?key=MyAPIKeyHere&id=1

Is there a way to get the API calls go as https://myappapi-asldfjoiewjfv-uc.a.run.app/v1/reports/results/1?key=MyAPIKeyHere ?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I have provided an answer below to your question. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/passing-data#setting_path_translation)

> Set `path_translation` as part of setting `x-google-backend`:
>
> ```
>    x-google-backend:
>      address: https://GCP_REGION-PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/hello
>      path_translation: [ APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS | CONSTANT_ADDRESS ]
> ```
>
> The default value of path_translation depends on where you set x-google->backend in your OpenAPI spec:
>
> - When x-google-backend is used at the top level of the OpenAPI specification, path_translation defaults to APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS.
> - When x-google-backend is used at the operation level of the OpenAPI specification, path_translation defaults to CONSTANT_ADDRESS.

For more details on path translation, please see the [Understanding path translation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions#understanding_path_translation) section. You can also check this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64805450/18265638).